# Not showing full url in meta property="og:url"

Tags: php, codeigniter, metadata

I'm trying to pass a variable from the function current_url() inside the content of the og:url,

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="[full url here]">
```

which should be:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.domainname.com/en/jobdetails?jobID=2&cpid=1&=job-title=Apply+now!+Web+Developer+-+Singapore">
```

while checking the view script in google chrome this one show:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.domainname.com/en/jobdetails">
```

Here's my code:

Library:

```
class Get_url{

        public function current_url(){
        
            $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
            $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            return $url;
          }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function jobdetails(){           
            $this->load->library('get_url');
            $data['cur_url'] = $this->get_url->current_url();           
            $this->load->view('head', $data, TRUE);
}
```

View:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>">
```

I tried to copy the code inside the function of current_url() and paste in my view to check if the full url are showing and yes it does.

Is there some restriction on passing a url on the meta property="og:url"?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns

> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance,
> '/index.html'.

and you want to add the parameters of the query, so you should add also the `QUERY_STRING` that you can access in the same way:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

and this will return

> The query string, if any, via which the page was accessed.